# Establishing a Client Server TCP connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to establish a Client Server setup using Python Socket Programming:

I have 2 different Machines(Both VMs). My server and client scripts run. But whatever I am sending from the client is not received on the server:

Server Code:

```
import socket

def Main():
 
    host = 'x.x.x.x' #Server ip
    port = 15099

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host, port))

    print("Server Started")
    while True:
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Message from: " + str(addr))
        print("From connected user: " + data)
        data = data.upper()
        print("Sending: " + data)
        s.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'), addr)
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

Client Code:

```
import socket

def Main():

    host='Y.Y.Y.Y' #client ip
    port = 15100
    
    server = ('X.X.X.X', 15099)
    
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind((host,port))
    
    message = input("-> ")
    while message !='q':
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)
        message = input("-> ")
    s.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    Main()
```

Am I missing something?

Also,

When I run the server and client on the same machine [with server as local host], it works fine. When they are 2 different machines, then it does not send any message.

Comment: Typo in server code `c.close()`. You mean s.close().

Comment: Edited. Thank you!

Comment: can the two VMs ping each other with the IPs used?

Comment: Yes, both able to ping each other. Same IPs given in the script too.

Comment: Typically, the server uses `('',port)` or `('0.0.0.0',port)` (same meaning) to listen on any interface the server supports, but your code (with and without the unnecessary bind in the client) works with `localhost` as the server.

Comment: When I run the server and client on the same machine [with server as local host], it works fine. When they are 2 different machines, then it does not send any message.

Answer (score 0):

The client does not need to bind to the socket. For the client, create the socket then call socket.sendto() with the host and port of the server.

Try this for the client:

```python
def Main():
    server = ('localhost', 15099) # replace with server IP_addr
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    while True:
        message = input("[enter q to quit] -> ")
        if message == 'q': break
        s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), server)
        data, _ = s.recvfrom(1024)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print("Received from server: " + data)
    s.close()
```

For the server, change the bind() call to this:

```
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
```

If the server doesn't get any connections after running the client then try running the client and server on the same machine.

Comment: Still the same problem. Whatever data I send does not show up on the server. I just sent "Hello". Doesnt work.

Comment: @SoftwareFan - try binding to 0.0.0.0 on the server to listen on every available network interface.

Comment: When I run the server and client on the same machine [with server as local host], it works fine. When they are 2 different machines, then it does not send any message.

Comment: @SoftwareFan - Sounds like not a python issue but configuration of the VM to open a port to remote connections. Depends on type of VM (Windows vs Linux) and/or VMWare vs VirtualBox, etc.

Comment: One VM is a  Windows (client) and the other one [server] is a CentOS. They can ping each other and firewall is disabled on the Windows side too. Is there something I can do to check if connection is being refused on the server?

Comment: Which host is server running on? Have you tried switching which VMs you're running the client and server from?

Comment: Actually, I need my windows to act as the client specifically. Since, this will be required as a base for me to run other tests :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236976/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-software-fan).